# file corresponds to /proc/locks

Tags: linux, files, lock

```
$ cat /proc/locks
1: POSIX ADVISORY  WRITE 458 03:07:133880 0 EOF
2: FLOCK ADVISORY  WRITE 404 03:07:133879 0 EOF
```

The fields are: ordinal number(1), type(2), mode(3), type(4), pid(5), maj:min:inode(6) start(7) end(8).

Question: how to find the corresponding file is being locked?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sudo find -L /proc/458/fd -maxdepth 1 -inum 133880 -print -exec readlink {} \;
```

To get all of them:

```
while IFS=': ' read x x x x p x x i x; do
  sudo find -L "/proc/$p/fd" -maxdepth 1 -inum "$i" -exec readlink {} \; -quit
done < /proc/locks
```

Sometimes, the process whose `pid` is referenced in `/proc/lock` will have died. You can change the `"/proc/$p/fd"` above to `/proc/*/fd` to look for them among all processes fds.

(note that it is an approximation as we're only checking the inode number, not the device number, but chances that we pick the wrong file (same inum on a different fs) are very slim).

Comment: This is a good answer if you are working in a limited environment like docker because it doesn't require any extra dependencies.  I extended this a little more, for my purposes, to print out the locking executable, followed by the locked file:
while IFS=': ' read x x x x p x x i x; do echo -e $p $i $(sudo readlink "/proc/$p/exe") $(sudo find -L "/proc/$p/fd" -maxdepth 1 -inum "$i" -exec readlink {} \; -quit 2>/dev/null || echo "ERROR:$?"); done < /proc/locks

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use `lslocks` instead of manual parsing `/proc/locks`

```
lslocks -nuo path | grep -x '/your/file'
```